# Flex DateTimeAxis: Displaying dates in another timezone (neither local nor UTC)

Tags: apache-flex, date, charts

I'm working with an AreaSeries + DateTimeAxis in Flex 4. The dates for the time axis originate from a server in another time zone. I'd like to see the graph (in my local time zone) displayed using the server's time zone.

I know that I can set the DateTimeAxis.displayLocalTime property to true or false, to have dates displayed in the local or UTC time zone. But the time zone I want is neither of those.

Is there a simple way to make DateTimeAxis work with another time zone? Or even a complicated way?

Thanks for any info. I have searched SO and other sites without finding anything.

Comment: Are the dates saved in the server UTC?

Comment: Hi, I am currently in the same position. Did you find a solution / workaround to this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the exact right solution to this problem but I can suggest a workaround for this - Pass the date as string arguments from flex-to-java-to-flex.

Answer (score 0):

This Time Zone Offset is largely dependent on your computer settings/localization.

You could change your computer settings to be the same as the server.  or.

If you want to display a different time zone offset, you would have to extract the UTC time, and subtract the time from there. and display it in a format that you require.  There is no setTimeZoneOffset() unfortunately.  You would also have to determine if the server has changed zones during Daylight Savings on certain days.  Better to just send a serialized date in the GMT from the server.